# javac in ProccessBuilder doesn't work in .jar?

Tags: java, process, javac

My problem is, when I build and run the application using its .jar(distribution ready), this code doesn't work.

```
 filepath = classpath + classname;   
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("javac", filepath + ".java");
 builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
 process = builder.start();
```

It works properly when I execute the program using Netbeans. But when it's on its own, it doesn't work.

I'm using `ProcessBuilder` and `Process` so that I can get the process' I/O stream later on.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Do you know about the [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)?

Comment: @miserable variable yes, I'd like to know how can I use JavaCompiler in exchange of process builder in compiling a class dynamically. Can you please give an example of it with the use of my filepath and can I put it in a process?

Comment: @MiserableVariable yes, I'd like to know how can I use JavaCompiler in exchange of process builder in compiling a class dynamically. Can you please give an example of it with the use of my filepath and can I put it in a process?

Comment: I am afraid `useleters` I cannot give example. But the API does not seem to be extremely complex; try it out and ask back here if you run into any difficulties or have specific questions

Comment: @MiserableVariable I tried the API, using `CompilationTask.call()` but it doesn't work when I'm using the application alone. It works when I run it with Netbeans but not on its own.. I did `JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        if(compiler == null){
            System.out.print("No compiler found");
        }else{
            System.out.print("Compiler found");
        }`
It returns `No compiler found` when I use the application alone.

Comment: Not sure why. I get a compiler both with `jdk/jre/bin/java` and `jdk/bin/java`. You might want to ask a separate question

Comment: @MiserableVariable I don't have javac.exe on my `jdk/jre/bin`. could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't have it either, maybe `jdk/jre/bin/java` created a compiler from `jdk/bin`? No idea.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans there is a development kit integrated into the environment. Due to this, it will always work with in there. Make sure your environmental variables are set to link to your JDK.

You can try this by going into a cmd.exe window and typing 'javac -version'. If done correctly, it should show the default JDK you have on your system. If it says it can't be found, follow this guide:

http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: I don't think this is the solution to my problem. But thank you for your reply.